# Running PHP from Perl Script

Tags: php, perl, drupal, fastcgi

I am attempting to run php scripts from a perl script on my goDaddy shared hosting.  The PHP script I originally wrote exceeds their 120 sec time limit and the mySQL memory limit, so I am breaking the script up into several parts.

I want this to all run as one cron job, so I want to call a single perl script that runs 4-5 php scripts.

This is for my website, run with Drupal 7.

I've written a perl script with the following content:

```
my $command = '/web/cgi-bin/php5 -q $HOME/html/phpscript1.php';
exec ($command) or print STDERR "couldn't exec $command: $!";
```

Which calls a php scripts containing something like the following:

```
<?php

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
....
do stuff
....
?>
```

But when I run this from perl (tried in both my $HOME directory and html directory) I see the following problems when I run the script (where XXXXXX is my godaddy account folder):

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  SCRIPT_NAME   
<b>/home/content/05/XXXXXXX/html/includes/bootstrap.inc</b> on line <b>1627</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  REMOTE_ADDR in    
<b>/home/content/05/XXXXXXX/html/includes/bootstrap.inc</b> on line <b>2802</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  argc in
<b>/home/content/05/XXXXXXX/html/includes/bootstrap.inc</b> on line <b>3290</b><br />
```

I've deduced that these are issues with FastGCI and that I probably need to define/export/point these index/variables to something, but I have been unable to find out what do to after extensive searching.

The PHP script copies images from an external server to my server using CURL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting php notices because you're bootstrapping Drupal in your custom php script, and those variables are not defined on the cli.

That php script would probably be better implemented as a [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) command. Drush already sets up all the variables Drupal expects to be defined, and gives you a framework for easily running custom code in an instance of Drupal. Even if you didn't want to bother writing a custom command, you could just use drush's script command like so:

```
drush scr $HOME/html/phpscript1.php
```

Also, it's worth pointing out that those are just php notices. It's unlikely they are causing any issues with your script.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments.  You are right about the code still running, but I was concerned about the errors.  I tried to install drush, but I don't think I can without root access (silly goDaddy)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer here is don't bootstrap Drupal as you would when working in your drupal site (e.g. creating functions in a module).  Rather, create a .php file that has the functions you need in it and use it outside of Drupal (e.g. above your html folder).  Thanks to Mark for the quick help.